# Ubuntu ldmtool not showing windows RAID-0 drive

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, raid-0

this used to work for me, but I've re-installed Ubuntu and now am not getting anywhere.

I have a dual-boot windows/Ubuntu machine. From windows I can see my RAID-0 drive, but when I use "sudo ldmtool scan" from ubuntu it is blank.

Any idea why it can't see the volume?

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what your command does.